# Line graphs in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a line graph in Tableau over the past 6 months and it is filtered by person. Some people have no data for certain months. When they do not have data, the graph appears blank for that month. I would like for the graph to show 0 instead of a blank. For example, if person A had no sales in February, I would like for the graph to show 0 for February rather than a blank for February. I cannot use the Zn function because there are no null values.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

Edit: Here is an example using false data

[image: Total Graph]

[image: Graph filtered by person]

The second graph is the same as the first graph except it is filtered by person. Even though Sally has no data in Feb, March, or June, this actually means that the value should be 0. I would like for the line graph to drop to 0 for these months. Further, then the average should be around 58 rather than 116.

Comment: could you please attach a screenshot of your line cart with blank data in order to better understand what's is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a data like the following:

```
Date        Person  Sales
15/01/2021  Peter   10
15/02/2021  Peter   20
15/03/2021  Peter   10
15/04/2021  Peter   30
15/05/2021  Peter   40
15/06/2021  Peter   20
15/01/2021  Sally   20
15/03/2021  Sally   10
15/05/2021  Sally   50
```

- Drag date into your colum shelf and make it Month-discrete
- Drag Sales into the worksheet
- Switch to line chart
- Right click Sales --> Format --> Pane --> Marks --> Show at default value
- Right click Month (Date) --> Show missing values
- Add Person as a Filter --> show Filter

Then you should be able to get something like this having Sally (just 3 out of 5 total months) showing her non existing 2 values as zero.

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me... The problem is that I have "no data" for April for a person so April is left blank. Because I have filtered the data by person, simply replacing the null values with 0 will not work. It seems as though tableau defaults to "null" when there is no data for a certain person.

Comment: By the way, this is important because having null values instead of 0 values messes up the per person average on the graph.

Comment: could you please attach a screenshot, otherwise it could be difficcult to guess what you're getting as result.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot :( my work is confidential

Comment: create a sample data instead of the original data

Comment: example provided :)

Comment: check the updated answer in few minutes

Comment: Thank you so much! & thank you for the data as well so I could follow along. This is *mostly* working for me... The only problem is when Sally only has sales in say February. In this case, I get a graph with a single dot on it showing February with no other months present. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: If the answer solved your need please accept it in order to mark the thread as closed...  the only way to fix that problem could be to add some additional rows in your dataset for each time period (say month) for each user with null values for metrics... this is something that you can't do with Tableau Desktop but you may try with an additional step prior using Tableau prep.

Comment: The info about Tableau prep is helpful for that problem. I have marked this as complete, but I have another additional problem still. When I add an average line on my end, I still get 80/3 = 26 for Sally rather than 80/5 = 16

Comment: do not use the average out of the box... try instead to do something like sum(Sales) dividing it for the overall count of months reegardless the user

Comment: That is a terrific idea that I didn't think of before. Thank you!